# Why are cookies called "cookies"?

Tags: servlets, cookies

In Servlets we have something called "Cookies". I know why Java got the name "Java" and why the Apple company got the name "Apple" and so on.

I would like to know why the name "Cookies" was chosen.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#History

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming.

Comment: This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the early 1970s a group of programmers working at Xerox came up with an idea for storing a bit of information on another computer. They appear to have called this little chunk of information a cookie after a character from the popular (at that time) Andy Williams Show.  This "Cookie Bear" character would follow Andy around asking for a cookie. The action of tracing these little files back to their original source is also referred to as following a trail of cookie crumbs.

[Source](http://www.siliconinvestor.com/readmsgs.aspx?subjectid=36800&msgnum=59909&batchsize=10&batchtype=Previous)